# Replacing values in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Been working on hangman using javascript and HTML, problem is whenever i click on a letter it doesn't replace the "_"

```
var myList=["Computer","Algorithm","Software","Programming","Developer"];
var n;
var star=" _";
console.log(myList)
computer=myList[Math.floor(Math.random() * myList.length)];
console.log(computer);
var word= document.getElementById("word").innerHTML=star.repeat(computer.length);
var letter=document.getElementsByClassName("col")
function myFunction(){
    n=word.replace(star,letter);
};
for (var i=0; i<letter.length;i++){
    letter[i].addEventListener("click",myFunction());
}
myFunction();
```

letter is basically alphabet(they are not buttons they are divs)
word is also an empty div in which the "-" goes in
in conclusion i want to replace word("-") with letters(which ever letter you click on)

Comment: `letter[i].addEventListener("click",myFunction());` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I just started javascript lately so i'm very clueless

Comment: from what i understand that it add an event to all elements of letter

Comment: i believe the problem is with my function not that part, because that part works whenever i press on any letter it executes the code below it but the function is not working

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It should be `addEventListener("click", myFunction)` without the `()`. You want to pass a reference to the function, not call the function immediately.

Comment: The function never updates the DIV after reassigning `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example:

```js
var myList=["Computer","Algorithm","Software","Programming","Developer"];
var star="_";
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

for(var i = 0; i<myList.length; i++) {
   var list = document.createElement('div');
   list.setAttribute('class', 'wrapper-list');
   list.setAttribute('id', 'list'+i);
   wrapper.appendChild(list);
   for(var j=0; j<myList[i].length;j++) {
      var item = document.createElement('div');
      item.setAttribute('class', 'wrapper-list__item');
      item.innerText = myList[i][j];
      list.appendChild(item);
      item.onclick = function(e) {
          this.innerText = star;
      }
   }
}
```

```css
.wrapper .wrapper-list {
    display: flex;
}

.wrapper .wrapper-list__item {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    margin: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```